# How to animate right/left hiding and showing divs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far my application is working when I click an event, the div moves to the left and the next div appears, so far so good. The first transition is working, but when I want to go back it doesn't work.

```
function animate_question(current_question, next_question, direction) {
    if (direction == "left") {
        $(current_question).animate({
            left: "-=100",
            opacity: "0"
        }, {
            "complete": function () {
                $(current_question).remove();
                $(next_question).delay(200).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    } else if (direction == "right") {
        $(current_question).animate({
            left: "+=100",
            opacity: "0"
        }, {
            "complete": function () {
                $(current_question).remove();
                $(next_question).delay(200).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Context

```
$("#next2").click(function() {
    var a = check_radio("Q1");
    if(a) {
        animate_question(".question1", ".question2", "left");
    } else {
        alertify.alert(message);
    }
});


$("#back1").click(function() {
    animate_question(".question2", ".question1", "right");
});
```

Comment: how can it come back, if you're removing it? can you show an example of how this function is used?

Comment: @KevinB done, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove` actually removes the element from the DOM. If you try again, there'd be no element to animate.

Comment: Oh, I see. What would you suggest I should do then?

Comment: Ditch the `$(current_question).remove();` statements.

Comment: Ok, it's not working, now, the next div is not positioning correctly.

Comment: you have to swap a few things around in your code, going from -= to += isn't enough. for example, you'll want to fadeOut and then animate if you wanted the animation to be completely opposite. The opacity will also need to go from 0 to 100 rather than 100 to 0

Comment: @KevinB Sounds reasonable,  although I'm having a little be of troubles translating your comment into code, would you mind providing a snipe of code?